# C++ friend class

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class Litak{
    public:
    int height;
    int weight;
    string name;
};

class Istrebitel : public Litak{
    private:
    int moch;
    public:
    friend void changeMoch( Istrebitel & moch);
    Istrebitel(int a){this->moch=a;}
};

class Pasachirskiy : public Litak{
    private:
    int places;
    //friend void setData(int,Pasachirskiy&);
    //public:
    Pasachirskiy(int a){this->places=a;}
};
class Perevisniy : public  Litak{
    private:
    int gryz;
    //friend void setData(int,Perevisniy&);
    //public:
    Perevisniy(int a){this->gryz=a;}
};

void changeMoch( Istrebitel& i){
    i.moch++;
}
main(){
    Istrebitel one(3);
    one.changeMoch();
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Укажите проблему.

Comment: Вместо прикладывания скрина лучше указывать сообщение об ошибке.

Answer (score 3):

Дружественная функция не является функцией-членом класса, который является дружественным. Поэтому вы не можете ее вызывать следующим образом

```
one.changeMoch();
```

Правильно будет написать

```
changeMoch( one );
```